# JavaFX on WindowsXP Error

Tags: java, windows-xp, javafx

I created a runnable .jar file from a project I built in Eclipse Juno.  The project uses the JRE7 and JavaFX libraries, which I added to the build path.

**Build Path Settings**
[image: Build Path]

The .jar file executes successfully on Windows 7 machines.  However, when I try to run the .jar file on a WindowsXP machine, it fails with the following linking error:

**Error on WindowsXP**
[image: Linking Error]

The error reads:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.invokeLater(Application.java:338)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.defer(QuantumToolkit.java:620)`

The error occurs just as the program tries to load a class that uses JavaFX, The WindowsXP machine has Java Version 7 Update 40 which comes with JavaFX, so I can't figure out why it would fail.

Could this be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit problem?

Also, on the build path settings, I wonder if I'm including the right JavaFX jar file.  I have two to choose from and I'm not exactly sure which one to include.  I assume it's the second one because it's part of the JRE.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfxtr.jar

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\jfxtr.jar

Thanks

Comment: Have you place the `JavaFX` dependency into `ant/maven` xml settings file?

Comment: No, I'm building it by exporting the project out of Eclipse as a runnable .jar file.  Do I need to use ant or maven?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `JavaFX` is embedded into `JRE`, but it is the separate library still now. So, if you use the `JavaFX` classes in your project, `JVM` should "know" about that. Your `*.jar` file should contain info about `jfxrt.jar`. **[How to do that?](http://blog.maurus.be/2012/12/02/javafx-and-maven/)**

**2.** `JRE` folder used for running the apps, such as `*.jar` files. `JDK/JRE` folder used when you developing your apps from IDE. So, you should use the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\` path for your project build path' libs.

Comment: Thank you!  So what is the difference between building a project with maven or ant versus exporting the project as a runnable .jar file?  Don't they both accomplish the same tasks -- to create a .jar file that can be run on any computer?

Comment: Sorry, it is an another question, post it as different one (with SSCCE, of course)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to run JavaFX applications on Windows XP.

Answer (score -1):

Despite all of my efforts, I couldn't get the .jar file to execute in Windows XP when I created it in Eclipse.  But I could get it to work when the project was exported out of NetBeans.  The trick was: I created a new "JavaFX in Swing Application" in NetBeans. That way, the IDE imported all of the necessary libraries for JavaFX.  I copied all of my .java files from Eclipse into the new NetBeans project and it worked. Happy with NetBeans!

Comment: which `all of the necessary libraries for JavaFX` would be?

Comment: That's not a fault of the IDE